# While loop not displaying string

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a function that prints the char array char by char in this function, the stream argument is just there for us to get used to the transition from java to C

```
public static int writeline (String message, PrintStream stream) {        
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    char[] array = new char[message.length()];

    for(int i = 0;  i < message.length(); i++){
        array[i] = new Character(message.charAt(i));
    }

    int index = 0;
    while( array[index] < message.length()){
         fputc(array[index],stream);
         index++;
    }
    return 0;
}  

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    System.err.print("Hola Mundo\n");
    writeline ("Hello World", System.out); 
}
```

The while loop  works only if i give a condition like `array[index] != null` but it will print the string with out of bounds exception error.
  Otherwise, with this nothing prints out. The main method just calls this method passing in a string and stream argument.

*edit* added main method for clarity

Comment: You might find this useful, [`String#toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) as opposed to creating your own implementation... Or is this meant to be a C question...

Comment: Not allowed to use any String method other than length and charAt, otherwise i would have used it instead

Comment: Ok, no worries then, but still is this meant to be java or C? `fputc` is not java

Comment: its in java, the professor wrote a fputc method for us so we can transition into C easier

Comment: That might have been something to tell us at the beginning. Also, I don't think giving Java, C characteristics is a good idea. If you get used to calling `fputc` while writing Java code, when you leave your professor you won't be used to calling `System.out.println();` instead. Mixing the languages is only gonna confuse you in the future IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're looping while the numerical value of each character in your string is less than the length of your string.  Here's an [ASCII chart](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/Images/ascii2.gif).  This gives the numerical value of characters.

Your string probably isn't more than the numerical value for 'a' or 'A' right?  So the loop's condition is false, and nothing is printed.

When you loop while `array[index]!=null` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the loop is true until the end of the array (as none of the elements in your array are null.)  Eventually you reference an index which doesn't exist.

What you want to do is loop while the value of index is less than the length of your character array.

```
while(index < array.length){
    //code code code ;)
}
```

If you are allowed to use a `for` loop here, I'd use it instead of the `while` as its slightly cleaner.

```
for(int index=0;index<array.length;index++){
    //same code.
}
```

Comment: o jeez.... what a silly mistake.... i didnt realize my error... thank you! long day :)

Comment: Haha, we all have off days!  If there's nothing else, when you get the chance, please accept an answer to close your question.  Thanks @ApprenticeProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

The following fix will loop until the index is equal to the length of the string:

```
int index = 0;
while( index < message.length()){
     fputc(array[index],stream);
     index++;
}
```